# Good way to stretch object over multiple classes

Tags: collections, mdi

I have a collection of orders. I would like to hit the database once, retrieve the orders, store them and then be able to access this collection over multiple forms. I know in asp.net, you can use things like Application Object or Session Object but how do you do it in a win form app? I was thinking of creating a static collection that could be accessed through multiple forms, classes, or wherever. Does this sound right and is it even feasible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental difference in WebForms & WinForms is that WinForms are stateful. In other words, you can ensure the objects you load once are available till the program is shutdown.  The same is not true for WebForms as HTTP is stateless and ASP.Net weaves lots of "magic" [ViewState, Server session, Cookies, Hidden fields etc.] to glue together pages of a web application.

With this basic concept of the way, it's easy to make an object globally available in WinForms.  Use a Singleton / Static class and assign its members.  You could always say .Instance.. [in case of static classes / classes with static properties] to retrieve values from any Form.

One Gottcha is "thread-safety"... aka.. multiple Forms reading / writing to the static property at the same time.  If you can take care of this, rest is a breeze.

For your above problem:

You could have your own Singleton Cache class that will cache records.  The Cache class will be a custom collection implementation.  You need to make sure that it's thread-safe [or make sure your application only Loads once and reads from then on]...  You may need to consider a full-fledged ORM if you want changes to the database reflected in your entity objects.

`CacheList.OrderCache[orderNo].Customer.Address.City = "Las Vegas";`

class static CacheList
{
      public static Cache OrderCache {get; internal set;}

}

public class Cache : CollectionBase where T : Entity
{
    .....

}

Answer (score 0):

You should have some Data Object that accesses the database anyways, right? Wrap that in a CacheProxy class, that hits the database if it doesn't have a local copy. I hear you can [use the System.Web cache in Winforms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cacheinwinformapps.aspx) as well.